# Install microk8s via snap using Ansible, on WSL 2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microk8s

I'm trying to install microk8s, using Ansible.

I get the error : "No snap matching 'microk8s' available"

I'm using WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04), and snap version 2.44.3+20.04.

My configuration:

```yaml
- name: Install microk8s
  snap:
    name:
      - microk8s
    classic: yes
  become: true
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: For anybody having trouble with this on Ubuntu 20 (without WSL), make sure to run the command to install the collection `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general`

Answer (score 2):

On the WSL terminal, what happens if you type: `snap version`.

It seems that [snap is broken](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5126) on WSL2 and using Ubuntu 20.04.

You could try to:

```sh
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME
```

It could also be a network/firewall issue. What happens if you try to install other packages.

Comment: I get: nsenter: failed to parse pid: '-a'

Comment: Snap requires systemd, which wasn't supported with WSL2 until the Windows 11 22H2 update and WSL installed from the Microsoft Store. Once you have those prerequisites you can configure WSL to run systemd. At that point you have a full Linux system and you can follow the MicroK8s instructions on how to install it.

Comment: MS taking their time…